# Error while installing libwally

Tags: ecdsa, installation, secp256k1, libwally

I am trying to install libwally on my debian machine. I followed the installation guide but running `./configure` I got the warning

```
=== configuring in src/secp256k1 (/home/standup/libwally-core/src/secp256k1)
configure: WARNING: no configuration information is in src/secp256k1
```

so when I run `make` I get the error

```
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/standup/libwally-core/src'
make  all-recursive
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/standup/libwally-core/src'
Making all in secp256k1
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/standup/libwally-core/src/secp256k1'
make[3]: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/standup/libwally-core/src/secp256k1'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1715: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/standup/libwally-core/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:927: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/standup/libwally-core/src'
make: *** [Makefile:436: all-recursive] Error 1
```

I see that it's an issue with the secp256k1 so I did some research and found [this suggestion](https://github.com/jgarzik/picocoin/issues/103) to install `secp256k1` seperately in the `/src` directory (I simply cloned [the repo](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1) and built it within `/src`).
This brought me a bit further (no warning while running `./configure`) but I still get this error after running `make`:

```
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/standup/libwally-core/src'
make  all-recursive
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/standup/libwally-core/src'
Making all in secp256k1
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/standup/libwally-core/src/secp256k1'
make  all-am
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/standup/libwally-core/src/secp256k1'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/standup/libwally-core/src/secp256k1'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/standup/libwally-core/src/secp256k1'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/standup/libwally-core/src'
  CC       ctest/test_bech32-test_bech32.o
  CC       libwallycore_la-address.lo
In file included from address.c:1:
internal.h:8:10: fatal error: secp256k1/include/secp256k1_ecdsa_s2c.h: No such file or directory
    8 | #include "secp256k1/include/secp256k1_ecdsa_s2c.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1324: libwallycore_la-address.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/standup/libwally-core/src'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1715: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/standup/libwally-core/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:927: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/standup/libwally-core/src'
make: *** [Makefile:436: all-recursive] Error 1
```

There is no `secp256k1/include/secp256k1_ecdsa_s2c.h` file ...

How can I fix this? It already seemed strange to me that I had to install the secp256k1 manually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use [ElementsProject/secp256k1-zkp](https://github.com/ElementsProject/secp256k1-zkp) rather than [bitcoin-core/secp256k1](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1). The Elements fork has a lot of extra modules used by libwally, including that missing `s2c` file (sign-to-contract).

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured that out, too! However shouldn't that be installed automatically? At least, it's part of the repository ..

Answer (score 0):

libsecp is installed as a submodule in the wally source tree. As per README, you need to run the following before building:

```
# Initialise the libsecp sources (Needs to be run only once)
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule sync --recursive
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
```